# Error: APK content must be streamed

Tags: android

I am trying to install the apk in the device but I am seeing "Error: APK content must be streamed" error. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
$ adb install –r test.apk
Failed to install test.apk: Error: APK content must be streamed
```

Comment: luckily found the solution. Earlier I copy pasted this command from mail to cmd and I observed this issue.But when I typed this command in terminal I did not observe this issue. May be when we copy paste from mails it is adding hidden characters. 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means you missed the actual path to the file (it's not there)

Comment: When I use RegEx in the path I get this error if there are multiple files matching the RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this with script to install APKs on multiple devices for code labs.

We think ADB was ignoring or struggling with "-s serialNo" vs. the environment variable. Seems odd we know.

Anyway, we basically set

```
ANDROID_SERIAL="serialNo"
```

then the

```
adb install ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this error typically when I make a typo in the file pathing or the file name itself.

One thing that helps me in these incidences is this:

```
abd install -r StartOfFileName*.apk
```

This is useful when you update your apk as well as to alleviate typo errors. The asterix suggests all or any entries after. Therefore, if you have a file named MyAwesomeAPKFileV7.apk

You could use:

```
abd install -r MyAwesome*.apk
```

With less characters typed, less room for error. Furthermore, when version 8 comes out [MyAwesomeAPKFileV8.apk] you don't need a new command or to rewrite your scripts, just replace the old APK and run the script again.